# Problemas con servidor proxy (squid) el servidor proxy está rechazando las conexiones solucion

Tags: windows

Tengo problemas con mi servidor proxy, he configurado el archivo "squid.conf" y este es el resultado.

```
#
# Recommended minimum configuration:
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt to list your (internal) IP networks from where browsing
# should be allowed

acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12  # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl mi_red src 192.168.0.104/255.255.255.0  # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src fc00::/7       # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10      # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

#
# Recommended minimum Access Permission configuration:
#

acl mi_red src "C:\Squid\etc\squid\permitidos.txt"

# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager

# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports

# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# We strongly recommend the following be uncommented to protect innocent
# web applications running on the proxy server who think the only
# one who can access services on "localhost" is a local user
#http_access deny to_localhost

#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt localnet in the ACL section to list your (internal) IP networks
# from where browsing should be allowed
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost

# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
http_access allow mi_red

# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 3128

# Uncomment the line below to enable disk caching - path format is /cygdrive/<full path to cache     folder>, i.e.
#cache_dir aufs /cygdrive/d/squid/cache 3000 16 256
cache_dir aufs C:\Squid\var\cache 3000 16 256


# Leave coredumps in the first cache dir
coredump_dir /var/cache/squid

# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320

dns_nameservers 8.8.8.8 208.67.222.222

max_filedescriptors 3200
```

el error que aparece en los navegadores es el siguiente: el servidor proxy está rechazando las conexiones solucion

Ya he investigado e intentado todo lo que he leído, pero sin exito.

en el archivo permitidos.txt, tengo la ip 192.168.0.104

El proxy lo estoy utilizando en una red interna para bloquear sitios web y dar acceso a otras direcciones IP, pero ya no le encuentro resultado a este error, ya intente con Google Chrome, Opera, Safari y FireFox, pero sigue saliendo el error, el proxy no lo puedo quitar del navegador, ya que es la conexión al servidor, ya el puerto 3128 del proxy esta habilitado en el firewall como TCP.

Comment: Prueba modificando esto: `acl mi_red src 192.168.0.104/255.255.255.0` por esto: `acl mi_red src 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0`, o bien por esto: `acl mi_red src 192.168.0.104/255.255.255.255`

Comment: Hola, me sigue rechazando la conexión. El servidor proxy está rechazando las conexiones

Comment: ¿y si haces un `telnet localhost 3128` desde la propia máquina donde esa el squid te acepta la conexión (seguramente se queda como pensando) o te sale un error de conexion (refused)?  ¿y si haces lo mismo desde otra máquina que te da? ¿y si pruebas abriéndolo todo en tu red primero con `acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/24`?

Comment: Ya lo he intentado, de hecho, elimino toda la configuración del squid proxy, y me sigue mostrando al instante: El servidor proxy está rechazando las conexiones.

Comment: acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/24 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src fc00::/7       # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10      # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
http_access allow all

Comment: ops, perdona, no lei bien las etiquetas... eso es un windows, je... puede ser cualquier cosa pues, ni idea... pero tengo mis dudas que esto este bien: `cache_dir aufs C:\Squid\var\cache 3000 16 256`... has mirado el log de errores de squid a ver si sale algo raro?

Comment: veo que tienes varios problemas tanto de forma como de fondo. Para no alargar la cosa, este es un enlace de ejemplo de un archivo de configuración de squid. Ajustalo a tus necesidades https://github.com/maravento/vault/blob/master/gateproxy/conf/server/squid.conf